# How to set shortcut for show/hide macvim?

Tags: vim, shortcut, macvim

I'm using macvim on Mac OSX and I found macvim doesn't provide shortcut for show/hide it self.
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Is that a Mavericks thing? It's supposed to have the regular `⌘H` shortcut like "every" other Mac OS X application.

Comment: @romainl Yeah. But `⌘H` could only hide this app.

Comment: Well, that's the point of `⌘H`, hiding the current app. Does it do thta or not? What do you want exactly? A global shortcut?

Comment: @romainl I want to get back to macvim as quick as possible no matter what window I focus in. Without this hotkey for macvim, I have to hit `Cmd+Tab` for many times(it is not effciency enough if I have many apps opened)

Comment: What about asking for what you need, then: how to create a global shortcut for a Mac OS X application. Or better, use google. FWIW, your question has nothing to do with Vim or MacVim, it's a very generic Mac OS X question with [a very generic Mac OS X answer](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463).

Comment: @romainl That's want I want! I should have google "How to Launch Any App with a Keyboard Shortcut"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using macvim within a terminal like iterm2 which provides a hot key to show / hide it. You can run macvim within a terminal using `mvim -v`.

Comment: It has some mapping problems with `<D-char>`. Refer to: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130730/vim-keyboard-mapping-problems-in-mac

Comment: That's really a small price to pay for the benefits you get by being within a terminal